# How to parse user input from a textarea line by line

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string

If I have a variable that contains text information (say taken from a textarea), how can I read the text content held in a string variable line by line?

The text entered in the text area will have \n (enter key) to separate the line.

Comment: a good question here is what is the default max length in a textarea? What is the scope we are working with?

Comment: few thousand lines, less than 10K.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx):

```
var reader = new StringReader(textbox.Text);
string line;
while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) {
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to use

```
string[] strings = yourString.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: This is inefficient for large strings.

Comment: @SLaks - Nothing was said about the size. So I assume that the size is reasonable.

Comment: You would have serious download and/or injection problems long before this becomes any less efficient than a StringReader.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but this could help!
Personally I use this code to handle all Operating System:

```
myString.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] splitInput = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(
                        InputString, "\r\n");
```

Comment: There is _really_ no point in using regular expressions here.

Comment: I think that using regular expressions is valid. Why not? Simple enough for me.