# html.textareafor - parse into an array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am in C# MVC (.NET) and have a form where I have input with @html.TextAreaFor
stored as a string
I am assuming that the data from this text box will store as a string, but what I am wondering is how will the string look, in terms of "/n" elements, will the string delimit new line markers?

Ideally, I need to parse the textbox line-by-line, where the string on each line becomes an element of a List
For example, if we have in the textbox

```
  item1
  item2
  item3
```

Then when I submit the form, the model that I specified will be loaded with the string form the textbox, and using that string we will load up our List (somewhere else, in a different model..)with item1, item2, and item3.

Comment: Use `List<string> list = new List<string>(); string[] lines = textareamodel.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, then use `foreach (string line in lines) { list.Add(line); }`. I can write as answer if this trick works.

Comment: Okay I will try it and see

Comment: It could be done in a single line `List<string> list = textareamodel.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()` .

Comment: @mmushtaq I agree with you by using `ToList()` as `List<string>`, but let's see if OP solves his problem first.

Comment: Verified it to work, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have `TextAreaFor` bound to a model property named `TextAreaModel` which contains strings from user input like this:

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TextAreaModel, new { ... })
```

The proper way to extract lines from model property is splitting the string content using `Environment.NewLine` as delimiter in POST action method as shown in example below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(ViewModel model)
{
    // other stuff   

    // parse every textarea lines as list elements
    List<string> list = model.TextAreaModel.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    // assign it to other list property on other model
    OtherModel.OtherList = list;

    // other stuff

    return View(model);
}
```

NB: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will remove empty lines found in source string, which I think this is more recommended way than using `StringSplitOptions.None`.

Demos:

[.NET Fiddle Example - Splitting By Newline](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J9aWDr)

[.NET Fiddle Example - MVC Implementation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLR3wi)

Related issue:

[How to parse user input from a textarea line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670203/how-to-parse-user-input-from-a-textarea-line-by-line)

Comment: I had to make sure I was storing the property as a string and not a string[] or the Split method is not applicable. Once I changed that it worked perfectly.